# Can Pivot's class relations be used in an Eloquent request

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I recently discovered "Pivot" classes in Laravel and was wondering if there is a way to use a Pivot class's relations in an Eloquent Query Builder.

Let's assume we have the followings:

- `User`, `Subject` and `Offer` Model *(where `subject` is Math, Sciences, etc. And `offer` is a purchasable item that contains courses)*
- `UserSubject` Pivot class (`user_id`, `subject_id`, `offer_id`, with BelongsTo relationships)

> At this point, we assume all our Models have implemented the correct relationships using the Pivot class.

I now would like to check if a User has a specific subject for a given offer's `type` (`Offer::TYPE_ONLINE_COURSE` for example):

```php
$user->hasSubject(Subject::MATH, Offer::TYPE_ONLINE)
```

1. Can pivot relationship be eager loaded ? (`pivot.offer`, for example)
2. Is it possible to use pivot's class relationship in a Query Builder:

```php
User::query()
    ->whereHas('subject', fn(Builder $query) => $query
        ->where('name', $subjectName)
        ->whereRelation('pivot.offer', 'type', $offerType)
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: You need the wherePivot/withPivot functions

Comment: I don't understand how you think it could fix my issue. WherePivot or withPivot methods works with columns and not relationships, from what I understand. However, I am trying to access a relationship method in my Pivot class, not a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can pivot relationship be eager loaded ? (pivot.offer, for example)

All relationships can be eager loaded, so the short answer is: Yes

> Is it possible to use pivot's class relationship in a Query Builder:

Yes, but you need to use different relationships. Lets look at the basic relationship first:

User model:

```
//Relation to all subjects belonging to user
function subjects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, 'user_subjects');
}
```

Subject model:

```
//Relation to all users belonging to subject
function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_subjects');
}
```

As you might have noticed here, you can get users from a subject and subjects from a user. You might actually use withPivot() to get the value of `offer_id`, but not the actual model.

You can add additional relationships to make this possible:

User model:

```
function userSubjects() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserSubject::class);
}
```

UserSubject model:

```
function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
function subject() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
}
function offer() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Offer::class);
}
```

Subject model:

```
function userSubjects() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserSubject::class);
}
```

Offer model:

```
function userSubjects() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserSubject::class);
}
```

With the last addition, you can load everything you want:

```
User::whereHas('userSubject', function($userSubjectQuery) use($offerType, $subjectName) {
    $userSubjectQuery
        ->whereHas('subject', function($subjectQuery) use($subjectName) {
            $subjectQuery->where('name', $subjectName);
        })
        ->whereHas('offer', function($offerQuery) use($offerType) {
            $offerQuery->where('type', $offerType); 
    });
});
```

The second set of `whereHas` is executed in perspective of the `UserSubject` model, which now has a queryable `offer` relationship.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It did solve my problem but still feels weird in the way that I feel like using this Pivot model like a regular Model (like a business entity). Anyway, still works and you saved me a lot of time, thanks a lot 